# Pushforward and pull back of the vector fields $x^n \partial _x + y^n \partial_y$

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, vector-fields

Given the vector fields $v_n=x^{n}{\partial_x}+y^{n}{\partial_y}$.

I am not sure how can I find the push forward $\phi^t_*v$ and the pull back ${\phi^{t}}^*dx\wedge dy$ where $\phi^t$ is the local flow of $v_1$.

I think for case $k=1$, it works nicely for global flow, but I am not sure for local flow, the push forward and pull back process could be the same as in the global flow or not.

Comment: Can you show us what you did for $k=1$ (or $n=1$?)

Comment: I'm not sure if $\phi^t$ stands for the flow of $v_n$ or just for the case $n=1$ (*i.e* the flow of $v_1$). In the case $n=1$ this is straight forward, and some more calculations are required for $n\neq 1$: just solve the equation $(x'(t),y'(t))=(x(t)^n,y(t)^n)$ and compute the flow.

Comment: n=1: $v_1=x^1\partial_x +y^1\partial_y$
$phi_{t}=x’(t),y’(t))=(xe^t,ye^t)$
$phi_{t}^-1 (u,v)=(ue^-t,ve^-t)$